# async.each final callback is being called before the iterators being called

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am running the following code with async.each. The final callback is getting called before all the iterators.

```
var async = require('async');

let filledArray = new Array(10);

for(let i=0; i<10;i++){
    filledArray[i] = {'name':'goodbye', id : i };
}

function printvals (it,  cb) {

    id = it.id;
    if ( (id % 2 ) == 0 ) {
        if ( id == 0 )
            setTimeout(console.log, 850, id);
        else
            setTimeout(console.log, id*100, id);
        }
        else {
            setTimeout(console.log, id*200, id);
        }
        cb(null);
    };

var finalCall = function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("error:", err);
        return console.log(err);
    }
    console.log('ok');
};

async.each(filledArray, printvals, finalCall);
```

I would have expected "ok" to be printed after all the iterators are executed. The output is actually as shown below, "ok" is printed before the iterators are executed.

```
ok
1
2
4
3
6
8
0
5
7
9
```

What am i missing here ? thanks

Comment: try this `async.each(console.log(filledArray), printvals, finalCall);`

Comment: Instead of using `async.each()` you may try ```for (const array of arrays) {}```

Comment: I want to use async.each for actually issuing a bunch of db calls in parallel and wait for all of them to finish and then have the final callback invoked. This is  a just a sample to get async.each working, before I embark on writing the actual code.

Comment: Your problem is that `printvals` does call the `cb` before it actually has finished logging the value. `async.each` can only wait for the callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very very close here! The `cb` passed into `printvals` needs to happen when the function is completed. `setTimeout` is a non-blocking operation, so you'd need to pass that `cb` into that function's callback.

The below should get you a lot closer. If you have any questions, let me know!

```
let filledArray = new Array(10);

for(let i=0; i<10;i++){
    filledArray[i] = {'name':'goodbye', id : i };
}

function myFunc(arg, cb) {
  console.log(arg);
  cb();
}

function printvals(it,  cb) {
  const id = it.id;
  if ( (id % 2 ) == 0 ) {
    if ( id == 0 ) {
      setTimeout(myFunc, 850, id, cb);
    } else {
      setTimeout(myFunc, id*100, id, cb);
    }
  } else {
      setTimeout(myFunc, id*200, id, cb);
  }
};

var finalCall = function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("error:", err);
        return console.log(err);
    }
    console.log('ok');
};

async.each(filledArray, printvals, finalCall);
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation and example, got it to work now

Answer (score 0):

The issue with `printvals`, even it has setTimeout which is async but you call `cb` before running timeout function. Please check the below correction.

```
function printvals(it, cb) {
  id = it.id;
  if (id % 2 == 0) {
    if (id == 0)
      setTimeout(
        id => {
          console.log(id);
          cb(null);
        },
        850,
        id
      );
    else
      setTimeout(
        id => {
          console.log(id);
          cb(null);
        },
        id * 100,
        id
      );
  } else {
    setTimeout(
      id => {
        console.log(id);
        cb(null);
      },
      id * 200,
      id
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @srinikv if it worked for u. please accept as answer! thanks.

Answer (score -1):

This happens because of how setTimeout(...) works.

setTimeout is not a blocking function/method. It returns immediately and the "console.log"-s are called later, possibly (in this case certainly) after your other code. This allows for async.each to finish the iteration and call the callback function before the first console.log is called.

For example:

```
setTimeout(console.log, 1000, '1');
console.log('2')
```

Would print:

```
2
1
```

Edit:
To clarify why async has nothing to do with this, here is a more detailed example with async included:

```
require('async')

function workload(taskId) {
    console.log('workload is executed for task ' + taskId);
}

function doCall(taskId) {
    console.log('doCall is called for task ' + taskId);
    setTimeout(workload, 1000 * taskId, taskId)
    console.log('doCall has finished executing for task ' + taksId);
}

function callback() {
    console.log('The callback was called');
}

function test() {
    let tasks = new Array(3);
    for(let i = 1; i <= 3; i++){
        tasks[i - 1] = i;
    }

    console.log("Just before async.each is called");
    async.each(tasks, doCall, callback)
    console.log("After async.each is called. Note the order of the tasks above is not guaranteed, nor relevant to the question");
}
```

This would print out:

```
Just before async.each is called
doCall is called for task 1
doCall has finished executing for task 1
doCall is called for task 2
doCall has finished executing for task 2
doCall is called for task 3
doCall has finished executing for task 3
The callback was called
After async.each is called. Note the order of the tasks above is not guaranteed, nor relevant to the question
workload is executed for task 1
workload is executed for task 2
workload is executed for task 3
```

This is how setTimeout works. Once again, it is a non blocking function.

Now to modify the example with a stub of a db call:

```
require('async')

function interactWithDb(taksId) {
    // Just a stub
    // For example reasons let us asume that it reads/stores something in the DB
    // and it takes some time to complete (for example 1 second)
    // Note this interaction with the DB is blocking
    // meaning it will not return until the call to the DB is over
}

function doCall(taskId) {
    console.log('doCall is called for task ' + taskId);
    interactWithDb(taskId);
    console.log('doCall has finished executing for task ' + taksId);
}

function callback() {
    console.log('The callback was called');
}

function test() {
    let tasks = new Array(3);
    for(let i = 1; i <= 3; i++){
        tasks[i - 1] = i;
    }

    console.log("Just before async.each is called");
    async.each(tasks, doCall, callback)
    console.log("After async.each is called. Note");
}
```

Would print out:

```
Just before async.each is called
doCall is called for task 1
doCall is called for task 2
doCall is called for task 3
doCall has finished executing for task 2
doCall has finished executing for task 1
doCall has finished executing for task 3
The callback was called
After async.each is called
```

Comment: async module is to help that issue, it should run all task before running final call. Read async module.

Comment: The async module does what it is supposed to do. It is not what is causing this behavior.
Just like the other answer has pointed out.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your suggestion. Now it is clear, what I was missing.